# How to remove the nested array object value with its Object ID in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i need to delete the url from the below mongodb database with the id which is in url object, then need the remaining data's as a result

My mongodb collection has the following :

```
    {
      "_id" : ObjectId("589b043abc2f5a467c13303b"),
      "user_id" : ObjectId("5874c174c813822341cb59a7"),
      "filename" : [
       {
         "url" : "images/product_images/file-1486554170465.jpeg",
         "_id" : ObjectId("589b043abc2f5a467c13303c")
       },
       {
         "url" : "images/product_images/file-1486554306440.jpeg",
         "_id" : ObjectId("589b04c2bc2f5a467c13303f")
       }]
    }
```

Can anybody help me please , thanks in advance ..

Comment: You can use the `select(['field1', 'field2'])` from Mongoose. Or you can do some post-processing with `_.pick()` or `_.omit()` from the Lodash library.

Comment: What all information do you have to fetch the document? Do you have the _id of the document and also the _id of the filename you want to remove?

Comment: i have userid,id of url and whole collection id , i need to remove the url .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mongoose you can do this -

```
CollectionInstance.findByIdAndUpdate(documentId, {
    $pull: {
        filename: {_id: urlId}
    }
}, {new: true});
```

By `documentId` I mean `589b043abc2f5a467c13303b` and by `urlId` I mean `589b043abc2f5a467c13303c` in your above example code.

What we are doing here finding is the particular document in the collection through its `_id` and then pulling the particular document from the `filename` array through its `_id`.

The `{new: true}` option tells Mongo to return the updated document. By default this value is false and Mongo returns the document state before update.

Comment: 'new_add_schema.findByIdAndUpdate("589d64e9e4aee71251c56941", 
        {
            $pull: 
            {
                filename:
                {
                    "_id": "589d6630866a0c1429f7e96a"
                }
            }
        }, 
        {
            new: true
        },
        function(req,vft)
        {
            console.log(vft)
        });'

Comment: I try the above , but its not delete the object(url and id)

Comment: woooow , its working fine now , after 3 days i get this result . thanks !! thanks a lot Jyotman Singh